# Im trying to update the email of a default user in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, email

I'm trying to update the default user model email with a Model Form and I messed something up in my views. How can I change the email to the input from the form.

heres my views

```
@login_required(login_url='home:login')
def ChangeEmailView(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = EmailChangingForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                emailvalue = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
                form = EmailChangingForm(instance=emailvalue)

   

            return redirect('home:profilesettings')
            
        else:
            form = EmailChangingForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'home/email_settings.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can handle your view to update a database object from a ModelForm :**

```
@login_required(login_url='home:login')
def ChangeEmailView(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailChangingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Retrieve the user
            user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
            # Update the user email
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            # Save the updated user
            user.save()
            # Redirect to profile
            return redirect('home:profilesettings')
    else:
        # It is a GET request
        userInstance = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        form = EmailChangingForm(instance=userInstance)
        context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'home/email_settings.html', context)
```